# UISegementController in top of UITableView

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios5, uitableview

I would like to add a UISegmentController in the top of my UITableViewController, just like in the AppStore.

[image]

I have tried googleing this but either I am search for the wrong things, or too view have written about this.

How can I do this, keeping it in the top with a different design than the UINavigationBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be a UITableViewController.  It might be just a UIViewController with a segment control at the top of the XIB and a tableview placed underneath the segment control.  That way, you could scroll the table view without scrolling the segment control.

Comment: I doubt it, but it sure could be. However, the question is not about how apple did it, but about how to do it with a `UITableViewController`.

Answer (score 2):

For style add segmentCont.segmentedControlStyle=7; which is same as the picture style.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is a custom header cell for the tableview. You should start by created a custom header with your segmented control inside that.

Comment: That sounds about right... however, how can i prevent the header from being pulled down?

Comment: Looks like most implementations build a custom header and add the tableview below that. May be your best bet.

Comment: If you add the segment control as the header cell of the table view, it'll get pulled down along with the rest of the table view cells.  If you do what I suggested above then the segment control won't move.  Doing it as a separate UIViewController isn't much harder than a UITableViewController.

Comment: @rekle you are right. It issn't much harder, however I dislike using the IB with XIB's. There is no use for it when using UITableViewControllers in my opinion (until now ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a ToolBar with UISegmentedControl or just UISegmentedControl and UITableView under it. You can place them (UISegmentedControl + UITableViewController) on UIScrollView and disable scroll for UITableView. You should make appropriate contentSize for your scrollview.

Comment: Seems to me like overkill for such a solution, but yeah you are right. Quite a pain in the ass to fix though without using IB, which I am not.

Comment: It's not difficult to create GUI without IB. Create scrollView -> add it on View -> create SegmentedControl with frame (0,0,320,SKheight) and delegate `self` -> add it on scrollview -> create UITableView with delegate and dataSource `self` and frame (0, SKheight,320,TableHeight) -> add it to scrollView. Also you may need to dynamically resize your tableView and contentSize of scrollView when number of cells changes.